# z-index issue on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, webkit

first of all I have very little experience with CSS/HTML, I'm not a webdesigner/coder, basically I have no clue what I'm doing.

I'm also close to kill myself because nothing helped. I really appreciate everyone who's trying to help me.

When you go on pawelpietryka.com and hover on the image it slides in a div via webkit transition and basically everything works.

I'm also using a webkit inset shadow which is animated too. I had big issues with this shadow because it always appeared behind the image (not in front) ... I hacked it with these changes

```
#demo-5 img { z-index: -1; position: relative; vertical-align: top; }
```

As soon as I put the z-index: -1; in it doesn't work on iPad/iPhone anymore, I'm tapping on the container and nothing happens.

(I'm assuming it doesn't have a hover state and when I'm trying to tap it it's somehow BEHIND the main layer.)

I've seen this on other page and the ideal scenario would be: 1) First tap box slides in 2) Second tap jump to destination.

Thanks!

Comment: When I remove `z-index` it still works the same for the browsers I tested, the shadow appeared in front of the image.

Comment: Sorry that was because I it was a png with transparency in it, now it has a white background, please try it again

Comment: if you gonna get rid off vertical-align: top; as well you gonna see that its behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of your div nesting as a pyramid such as...

```
<pyramid>
  <section level="1">
    <section level="2">
    </section>
  </section>
</pyramid>
```

You can't get level 2 to appear under level 1, because level 1 *contains* level 2. If you would want level 2 to appear over level 2, usually they would be siblings, i.e

```
<pyramid>
  <section level="1"></section>
  <section level="2"></section>
</pyramid>
```

But in your specific case, I would recommend putting the image as the background of the div

```
<div id="boxes">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="rel" id="demo-5" style="background: transparent url(<?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?>) top left no-repeat">
          <div class="detailsausgeblendet">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time!

I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work (probably because I don't know how to implement the php sytax from wordpress.

I've changed it to 

<div id="boxes">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <div class="box">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="rel" id="demo-5" style="background-image:<?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?>">
     <div class="detailsausgeblendet">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php the_excerpt() ?>
     </div>
     

 <?php endif ?>
   
  </div></a>
 </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

Comment: I updated the answer, try it and let me know how it goes. You have a stray endif that I removed, just a case it generates an error on your side.

Comment: I think you are very close: The images don't show up but you can hover over the boxes, also it has the same behaviour on the iPad!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to post it here, the formatting is odd on comments

```
<div id="boxes">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="box">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="rel" id="demo-5" style="background-image:<?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb'); ?>">
                    <div class="detailsausgeblendet">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    </div>


    <?php endif ?>

        </div></a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is the code 'unchanged'

```
<div id="boxes">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="rel" id="demo-5">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
    <?php if ($imbalance2_theme_options['images_only'] == 0): ?>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="detailsausgeblendet">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    </div></a>


    <?php endif ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```